# OneToOne in Hibernate causes StackOverflow Exception when calling Mongo save

Tags: spring, mongodb, hibernate

I have two entities :

**Invoice :**

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "invoices")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Invoice implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "invoice")
    private InvoiceSequence invoiceSequence;
... // skipped for brevity
```

**InvoiceSequence**

```
@Entity
public class InvoiceSequence {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long seqId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Invoice invoice;
... // skipped for brevity
```

When calling mongo save,as in :

```
@Override
    public Invoice save(Invoice invoice) {

        Invoice savedInv = invoiceRepository.save(invoice);
        InvoiceSequence seq = new InvoiceSequence();
        seq.setInvoice(savedInv);
        InvoiceSequence savedSeq = invoiceSequenceRepository.save(seq);
        savedInv.setInvoiceSequence(savedSeq);

        return savedInv;
    }
```

i get :

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Class.isInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3368)
    at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Accessor.checkCast(DirectMethodHandle.java:418)
    at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.checkCast(DirectMethodHandle.java:487)
    at com.vulog.billing.domain.Invoice_Accessor_5oixbb.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:432)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:425)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:330)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:425)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:527)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:437)
```

What am i missing?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you any other annotation on top of the class? For example is InvoiceSequence annotated only by 'entity'?

Comment: this it. only @Entity

Comment: invoice has some index, but i omitted for brevity. @Table(name = "invoices", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "IDX_FLEET", columnList = "fleetId", unique = false)
        ,
        @Index(name = "IDX_USERSSS", columnList = "userId", unique = false)
        ,
        @Index(name = "IDX_TIME", columnList = "invoiceDate", unique = false)
})

Comment: i ve added the save method in the service, in case it helps